# Username and password for postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have installed postgresql in ubuntu.

But i need to know the username and password for it?

If i have to set it, how do i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to know postgresql's password.Because by default,postgresql trust local os users.So you can login postgresql without password:

```
psql -d db -U postgres
```

then you can change you password:

```
alter user postgres password 'password';
```

Comment: This sudo -u postgres psql template1 worked for me from https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/postgresql.html. Your command gives: $ psql -d db -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the [Ubuntu-manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/postgresql.html)?